# MacBook Pro LED light flashing

Tags: macbook-pro, skype

My LED light on my MacBook Pro flashes off for about 0.1 second then turns back on and will flash off again for the same amount of time while I'm using Skype.  Is someone spying on my camera?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking of the camera status indicator LED. If it turns on for a svery short time, it means that some program tried to access the camera. From your description this is likely Skype.

As far as I remember there was a problem similar to this in an earlier version of Skype where it repeatedly tried to initialize the camera. Update your Skype to ensure this is not the case.

If that doesn't help, then check the camera settings in Skype. For example try not selecting your built-in camera as a video source in Skype at all. If that cures the flashing light, you know that the cause is Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Video calling on Skype requires very solid network connection since it handles huge amount of streaming (up and down) data.

So check that you have:

- solid Internet connection during the Skype calls.

To do that you can use the build in function Wireless Diagnostics.

It is but hidden, but here you go.

Hold Option key <kbd>alt</kbd> and click on the WiFi icon on the top bar.

All the way at the bottom of the pop up window you will find the Open Wireless Diagnostics.

In there press <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>

Now select performances tab that will show a graph

- let it run.

Make your Skype Video call.

Occasionally check the Graph window to make sure the Green line stays up at all times and the blue is as low as possible.

It looks like this:

[image: wifi]